# How to get papers from a Conference from Microsoft Academics API

Tags: python, azure, academic-graph

I've been using [Microsoft Academic Knoledge API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/cognitive-services/academic-knowledge/) for a week, I didn't have any problems until now. I want to get all the papers from a conference, for example, ICLR or ICML. I'm trying with the following query that I got from the "interpret" method:

```
        'expr': "Composite(C.CN=='iclr')",
        'model': 'latest',
        'count': '100',
        'offset': '0',
        'attributes': 'Ti,D,C.CN,AA.AuN,AA.AfN,F.FN,CC',
```

But I'm just getting one paper, not an array of results:

```
{'authors': 'Karen Simonyan, Andrew Zisserman', 'affiliations': 'University Of Oxford, University Of Oxford', 'citations': 3249, 'fields': 'Theoretical Computer Science, Computer Vision, Machine Learning, Computer Science'}
```

Is there any way to get all the results at once?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `count` field to adjust the number of items you want to see.

For example, the following shows 100 results (ordered by year, descending -- note the `count=100&orderby=Y:desc`):

```
https://api.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/academic/v1.0/evaluate?&expr=Composite(C.CN==%27iclr%27)&count=100&orderby=Y:desc&attributes=Ti,D,C.CN,AA.AuN,AA.AfN,F.FN,CC&subscription-key={YOUR-KEY}
```